# Efficient way of XML parsing in ElementTree(1.3.0) Python

Tags: python, xml, performance, parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse a huge XML file ranging from (20MB-3GB). Files are samples coming from different Instrumentation. So, what I am doing is finding necessary element information from file and inserting them to database (Django).

Small part of my file sample. Namespace exist in all files. Interesting feature of files are they have **more node attributes then text**

```
<?xml VERSION="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<mzML xmlns="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.0.xsd" accession="plgs_example" version="1.1.0" id="urn:lsid:proteios.org:mzml.plgs_example">

    <instrumentConfiguration id="QTOF">
                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000189" name="Q-Tof ultima"/>
                    <componentList count="4">
                            <source order="1">
                                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000398" name="nanoelectrospray"/>
                            </source>
                            <analyzer order="2">
                                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000081" name="quadrupole"/>
                            </analyzer>
                            <analyzer order="3">
                                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000084" name="time-of-flight"/>
                            </analyzer>
                            <detector order="4">
                                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000114" name="microchannel plate detector"/>
                            </detector>
                    </componentList>
     </instrumentConfiguration>
```

Small but complete file is [**here**](http://psidev.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/psidev/psi/psi-ms/mzML/instanceFile/tiny2_SRM.mzML0.99.1.mzML)

So what I have done till now is using findall for every element of interest.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('plgs_example.mzML')
root=tree.getroot()
NS="{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}"
s=tree.findall('.//{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}instrumentConfiguration')
for ins in range(len(s)):
    insattrib=s[ins].attrib
    # It will print out all the id attribute of instrument
    print insattrib["id"]
```

**How can I access all children/grandchildren of instrumentConfiguration (s) element?**

```
s=tree.findall('.//{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}instrumentConfiguration')
```

**Example of what I want**

```
InstrumentConfiguration
-----------------------
Id:QTOF
Parameter1: T-Tof ultima
source:nanoelectrospray
analyzer: quadrupole
analyzer: time-of-flight
detector: microchannel plate decector
```

Is there efficient way of parsing element/subelement/subelement when namespace exist? Or do I have to use find/findall every time to access particular element in the tree with namespace? This is just a small example I have to parse more complex element hierarchy.

Any suggestions!

**Edit**

Didn't got the correct answer so have to edit once more!

Comment: Your XML does not have any instrumentConfiguration in it so you should be finding nothing.

Comment: It's fine now. I copied different sample example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's  a script that parses one million `<instrumentConfiguration/>` elements (`967MB` file) in `40` seconds (on my machine) without consuming large amount of memory.

The throughput is `24MB/s`. The [`cElementTree page (2005)`](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm#benchmarks) reports `47MB/s`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import imap, islice, izip
from operator  import itemgetter
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

def parsexml(filename):
    it = imap(itemgetter(1),
              iter(etree.iterparse(filename, events=('start',))))
    root = next(it) # get root element
    for elem in it:
        if elem.tag == '{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}instrumentConfiguration':
            values = [('Id', elem.get('id')),
                      ('Parameter1', next(it).get('name'))] # cvParam
            componentList_count = int(next(it).get('count'))
            for parent, child in islice(izip(it, it), componentList_count):
                key = parent.tag.partition('}')[2]
                value = child.get('name')
                assert child.tag.endswith('cvParam')
                values.append((key, value))
            yield values
            root.clear() # preserve memory

def print_values(it):
    for line in (': '.join(val) for conf in it for val in conf):
        print(line)

print_values(parsexml(filename))
```

#### Output

```
$ /usr/bin/time python parse_mxml.py
Id: QTOF
Parameter1: Q-Tof ultima
source: nanoelectrospray
analyzer: quadrupole
analyzer: time-of-flight
detector: microchannel plate detector
38.51user 1.16system 0:40.09elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 23360maxresident)k
1984784inputs+0outputs (2major+1634minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Note: *The code is fragile* it assumes that the first two children of `<instrumentConfiguration/>` are  `<cvParam/>` and `<componentList/>` and all values are available as tag names or attributes.

#### On performance

ElementTree 1.3 is ~6 times slower than cElementTree 1.0.6 in this case.

If you replace `root.clear()` by `elem.clear()` then the code is ~10% faster but ~10 times more memory. `lxml.etree` works with `elem.clear()` variant, the performance is the same as for `cElementTree` but it consumes 20 (`root.clear()`) / 2 (`elem.clear()`) times as much memory (500MB).

Comment: The assumption regarding instrumentConfiguration having same number of subelement is wrong for my purpose. cvParam occurance in number does differ!

Comment: @thchand: This limitation can be easily lifted. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I will cross check before accepting answer, but already upvoted

Comment: @thchand: To run it on real data more checks should be added to make sure that you get expected tag names, attribute values. If not then either recover e.g., skip until a known tag is found and/or log some diagnostic information about where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

If this is still a current issue, you might try pymzML, a python Interface to mzML Files.  Website:
http://pymzml.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would get findall to find all the instrumentList elements. Then on those results just access the data as if instrumentList and instrument were arrays, you get all the elements and don't have to search for them all.

Comment: Can you be more specific wth examples?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are huge, have a look at the [`iterparse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) function. Be sure to read [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm)
by elementtree's author, especially the part about "incremental parsing".

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but I run into this issue while doing XML parsing, where my XML files where really large.

J.F. Sebastian's answer is indeed correct, but the following issue came up.

What I noticed, is that sometimes the values in elem.text ( if you have values inside XML and not as attributes) are not read correctly (sometimes None is returned) if you iterate through the start attributes. I had to iterate through the 'end' like this

```
it = imap(itemgetter(1),
          iter(etree.iterparse(filename, events=('end',))))
root = next(it) # get root element
```

If someone wants to get the text inside an xml tag (and not an attribute) maybe he should iterate through the 'end' events and not 'start'.

However, if all the values are in attributes, then the code in J.F. Sebastian's answer is more correct.

XML example for my case:

```
<data>
<country>
    <name>Liechtenstein</name>
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Singapore</name>
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Panama</name>
    <rank>68</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
</country>
```