# Parsing compressed xml feed into ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, gzip, elementtree

I'm trying to parse the following feed into ElementTree in python: "http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml" (warning large file)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
feed = urllib.urlopen("http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml")

# feed is compressed
compressed_data = feed.read()
import StringIO
compressedstream = StringIO.StringIO(compressed_data)
import gzip
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedstream)
data = gzipper.read()

# Parse XML
tree = ET.parse(data)
```

but it seems to just hang on `compressed_data = feed.read()`, infinitely maybe?? (I know it's a big file, but seems too long compared to other non-compressed feeds I parsed, and this large is killing any bandwidth gains from the gzip compression in the first place).

Next I tried `requests`, with

```
url = "http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml"
headers = {'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
```

but now

```
tree=ET.parse(r.content)
```

or

```
tree=ET.parse(r.text)
```

but these raise exceptions.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: "these raise exceptions" isn't helpful. _What_ exceptions? Copy and paste the traceback into your question.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to pass an HTTP header as POST data? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ET.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) function takes "a filename or file object containing XML data". You're giving it a string full of XML. It's going to try to open a file whose name is that big chunk of XML. There is probably no such file.

You want the [`fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) function, or the [`XML`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML) constructor.

Or, if you prefer, you've already got a file object, `gzipper`; you could just pass that to `parse` instead of reading it into a string.

---

This is all covered by the short [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial) in the docs:

> We can import this data by reading from a file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

> Or directly from a string:

```
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the value returned by `urlopen()` directly to `GzipFile()` and in turn you can pass it to `ElementTree` methods such as `iterparse()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from gzip import GzipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

with urlopen(Request("http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml",
                     headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"})) as response, \
     GzipFile(fileobj=response) as xml_file:
    for elem in getelements(xml_file, 'interesting_tag'):
        process(elem)
```

where `getelements()` allows to parse files that do not fit in memory.

```
def getelements(filename_or_file, tag):
    """Yield *tag* elements from *filename_or_file* xml incrementaly."""
    context = iter(etree.iterparse(filename_or_file, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context) # get root element
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == tag:
            yield elem
            root.clear() # free memory
```

To preserve memory, the constructed xml tree is cleared on each *tag* element.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on `root.clear()` ? How does this free the memory for each `elem` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the last sentence says what `root.clear()` does and why it is used.

Comment: Thanks - what confuses me is that root seems defined once - I would expect something like `elem.clear()`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: here's [on the difference between `elem.clear()` and `root.clear()`](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing) (in short: unless the xml file is huge, we can ignore it). Here's [on the performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943376/4279)