# Porting from Python 2 to Python 3: 'utf-8 codec can't decode byte'

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, stringio

Hey I tried to port that little snippet to Python 3 from 2.

Python 2:

```
def _download_database(self, url):
  try:
    with closing(urllib.urlopen(url)) as u:
      return StringIO(u.read())
  except IOError:
    self.__show_exception(sys.exc_info())
  return None
```

Python 3:

```
def _download_database(self, url):
  try:
    with closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) as u:
      response = u.read().decode('utf-8')
      return StringIO(response)
  except IOError:
    self.__show_exception(sys.exc_info())
  return None
```

But I'm still getting

```
utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 12: invalid start byte
```

I need to use StringIO since its a zipfile and i want to parse it with that function:

```
   def _parse_zip(self, raw_zip):
  try:
     zip = zipfile.ZipFile(raw_zip)

     filelist = map(lambda x: x.filename, zip.filelist)
     db_file  = 'IpToCountry.csv' if 'IpToCountry.csv' in filelist else filelist[0]

     with closing(StringIO(zip.read(db_file))) as raw_database:
        return_val = self.___parse_database(raw_database)

     if return_val:
        self._load_data()

  except:
     self.__show_exception(sys.exc_info())
     return_val = False

  return return_val
```

raw_zip is the return of the download_database func

Comment: The encoding of the data you received is, apparently, *not* UTF-8.  What encoding is it?  If the web server is correct, then the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response should tell you, as well as potentially an HTML `<meta>` tag in the document (if it is HTML).

Comment: The default encoding on many webservers is iso-8859-1.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python-3]+codec+can%27t+decode+answers%3A1) are existing questions on StackOverflow with answers explaining decoding bytes to characters.

Comment: the url im retrying is http://software77.net/geo-ip?DL=2

Comment: That url is downloading a zip file -- why are you trying to convert a binary file into a string?

Comment: I added an answer for what im doing next with that..

It worked in python2 but dont know why not in python3

Comment: Python 2 does not have a clear separation between `binary` and `text`, but Python 3 does: binary data is `bytes` and text is `str`.  `raw_zip` should be binary, so you don't need to decode it.

Comment: @Fragkiller As others have noted, you are retrieving a binary file, not text.  Ashley Wilson's answer shows how to get the bytes. The reason it "worked" in Python 2 is because Python 2 was very sloppy regarding bytes versus characters and didn't handle Unicode well. In Python 3 you need to understand the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

utf-8 can't decode arbitrary binary data.

utf-8 is a character encoding that can be used to encode a text (e.g., represented as `str` type in Python 3 -- a sequence of Unicode codepoints) into bytestring (`bytes` type -- sequence of bytes (small integers in [0, 255] interval)) and decode it back.

utf-8 is not the only character encoding. There are character encodings that are incompatible with utf-8. Even if `.decode('utf-8')` hasn't raised an exception; it doesn't mean that the result is correct -- you may get [*mojibake*](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx) if you use a wrong character encoding to decode text. See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

Your input is a zip-file -- binary data is not text and therefore you should not try to decode it to text.

Python 3 helps you to find errors related to mixing binary data and text. **To port code from Python 2 to Python 3, you should understand text (Unicode) vs. binary data (bytes) distinction.**

`str` on Python 2 is a bytestring that can be used for binary data and (encoded) text. Unless `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is present; `''` literal creates a bytestring in Python 2. `u''` creates `unicode` instance. On Python 3 `str` type is Unicode. `bytes` refers to sequence of bytes on both Python 3 and Python 2.7 (`bytes` is an alias for `str` on Python 2). `b''` creates `bytes` instance on both Python 2/3.

`urllib.request.urlopen(url)` returns a file-like object (binary file), you could pass it as is *in some cases* e.g., [to decode remote gzipped content on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from gzip import GzipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

with urlopen(Request("http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml",
                     headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"})) as response, \
     GzipFile(fileobj=response) as xml_file:
    for elem in getelements(xml_file, 'interesting_tag'):
        process(elem)
```

`ZipFile()` requires a `seek()`-able file and therefore you can't pass `urlopen()` directly. You have to download the content first. You could use `io.BytesIO()`, to wrap it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/channel.zip"
with urlopen(url) as r, zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.read())) as archive:
    print({member.filename: archive.read(member) for member in archive.infolist()})
```

`StringIO()` is text file. It stores Unicode in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're interested in is returning a stream handler from your function (rather than having a requirement to decode the content), can you use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`:

```
from contextlib import closing
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://www.google.com'


with closing(urlopen(url)) as u:
    response = u.read()
    print(BytesIO(response))
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted, `http://software77.net/geo-ip?DL=2` is trying to download a `zip` file, which is binary.

- You shouldn't convert a binary blob to a `str` (just use `BytesIO`)
- If you have a really good reason to do so anyway, use `latin-1` as the decoder.